# How to set up this LED R7s lamp?

Tags: electrical, led

I would like to install an [Osram LED R7s lamp](https://www.conrad.com/p/osram-led-eec-a-a-e-r7s-rod-15-w-125-w-warm-white-x-l-29-mm-x-118-mm-dimmable-1-pcs-1559672) using [this holder](https://www.conrad.com/p/basetech-bulb-holder-r7s-230-v-1500-w-1465112) in my living room.

Now I'm wondering whether I can just hook it up with the AC like I would do with regular LED bulbs or do I need some sort of modulator between the lamp and the AC?

Or to put it even more blatantly naive: the picture of the holder shows two wires - can I solder those to a plug and stick it in the socket?

"Technically speaking" it says that the operating voltage is 230V which is the case for AC in Germany but I just want to be sure.

Comment: This is an electronics question, not home improvement. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

Those things are *components*.  You're not allowed to use components directly in a house.

You need to use a **fixture** which is designed to be used for household lighting.  These are sold in home improvement stores.  The manufacturer has gone through the appropriate process to get listed and tested **as a fixture** - so there's a stamp (and file number) from TUV, BSI, CSA, UL, ETL or other competent testing lab. CE is not a testing lab.

If you were to start up a company to manufacture fixtures, you would make the fixtures out of components such as those sold by Conrad. (Presumably, though, you'd pay wholesale).

Conrad sells them to the consumer as repair parts for fixtures.

If you want to "brew your own" built-in lighting, then use low-voltage lighting (12-24V) fed from listed low-voltage transformers.  You must still use care, but it sidesteps some of the safety issues.

Further, use either socketless LEDs, or sockets which are unique to LEDs.  What you have linked is a **halogen** socket, with an LED designed to be retrofit into a halogen fixture.  Nothing would keep someone from yanking out that LED and sticking a real 500W halogen bulb in there.  So don't give them the opportunity.